# PHP preg_match() function to search HTML element

Tags: php, preg-match, dom

I have HTML output and want to search a specific element on HTML DOM, let say below:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="post">
            <div>
                <h3><a>Post Title Here</a></h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

with that HTML output, from that i wanted to get the text inside  tag using preg_match function. How am i going to format it on preg_match?

Answers are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is there a reason you suggest using `preg_match`?

Comment: **Do not parse HTML with regexps** - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: @ThiefMaster thanks for that link, I was looking for it :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not :) Parse the HTML with a proper HTML parser: less headache, much better handling. See here:

[How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-with-php)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [phpQuery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/) like this:

```
phpQuery::newDocumentHTML($yourHTML);
$resultData = pq('div#post h3 > a');
echo $resultData; // Post Title Here
```